# Changing color of an animated responsive button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I cannot change the color of a responsive bootstrap button in CSS.

I'm using Bootstrap 3 with Html.

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-center"> 
 <a data-animation="animated fadeInUp" class="header-requestbtn contactus-btn hvr-bounce-to-right" href="site/indexfdd4.html">PRODUCTS!</a></div> 
    <style>
        .header-requestbtn contactus-btn hvr-bounce-to-right {

         background-color: grey;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: You need to concatenate with `.` your css classes or just use one of them: `.header-requestbtn.contactus-btn.hvr-bounce-to-right` or just use `.header-requestbtn` and get rid of the rest of the classes in your style tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is wrong.

```
.header-requestbtn.contactus-btn.hvr-bounce-to-right {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```html
<div class="col-md-12 text-center"> 
    <a data-animation="animated fadeInUp" class="header-requestbtn contactus-btn hvr-bounce-to-right" href="site/indexfdd4.html">PRODUCTS!</a>
</div> 

<style>
.contactus-btn {
      background-color: grey;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to change the color on hover, you need to add the `:hover` state to the end of the class

`.header-requestbtn.contactus-btn.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover {
       background: grey;
    }`

Comment: I don't think `hover` is the issue. It's the fact their CSS classes were not set correctly (which you did show correctly) in the style tag.

Comment: Well I've fixed those too. But hard to tell as the question was a little vague

Answer (score -1):

I had an issue with your spacing for the class name

here would be corrected code

```
<html>
    <style>
    .header-requestbtn_contactus-btn_hvr-bounce-to-right {
        background: grey;

}


</style>


  <div class="col-md-12 text-center"> 
    <a data-animation="animated fadeInUp" class="header-requestbtn_contactus-btn_hvr-bounce-to-right" href="site/indexfdd4.html">PRODUCTS!</a></div> 



</html>
```

Comment: It's a really bad idea to change the OPs classes. What if `contactus-btn` or `hvr-bounce-to-right` classes added different properties? This could break their code even more.